# Best DJango module to create Dashboard?

Tags: django, python-3.x

What the best DJango module to create Dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to get in the end.
I can offer you the following:

[dashing](https://github.com/talpor/django-dashing), [controlcenter](https://github.com/byashimov/django-controlcenter), [dash](https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-dash) (Specifically with this, I did not work), [django-admin-tools-stats](https://github.com/areski/django-admin-tools-stats)

Comment: I would like to get the opinion of everyone as to what is the best way to build Dashboard from the information contained in a database, create graphs and KPIs and submit to the user via the web.

Comment: In what form do you want to send information to the user?

Comment: The User must access via Web Page

Comment: @JulianoBarbosa, see at https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-dash
There is a link to the demo